# asp.net mvc 3: how can I use just 1 config file for my whole solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a asp.net mvc 3 solution with a few projects ( WCF, DAL UI etc). Is it possible to stick all the config settings in just 1 web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
Other web configs (not the root one) just override some specific for that folder (views) settings, nothing more.

- [ASP.NET MVC – how we do configuration](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/ASPNET-MVC-e28093-how-we-do-configuration.aspx)
- [10 Things ASP.NET Developers Should Know About Web.config Inheritance and Overrides](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx)